# Html for loop add another condition

Tags: html, css, django

I want to fetch the data in html template by for loop. Here's what my code is.

```
    {% for entry in topic.entries.all %}
        <li>
        <a style="line-height:170%", href="{% url 'xx' entry.id %}">{{ entry.text }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

And I need to add one additional condition to identify if the Entry Model field 'delete' = '1'. I try {% for entry in topic.entries.all().value_list(delete = '1') %}, but id did not work. How could I achieve that? Here's the Model.py.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delete = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def _str_(self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entries")
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delete = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def _str_(self):
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
        #on_delete=models.CASCADE,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an if condition inside the for loop.

```
{% for entry in topic.entries.all %}
    {% if entry.delete == 1 %}
        <li>
            <a style="line-height:170%", href="{% url 'xx' entry.id %}">{{ entry.text }}</a>
       </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can get the queryset according to the delete condition inside the context variable and then traverse over it in the template (rather than bringing topic and then finding all entries associated with it).

```
# views.py
entries = topic.entries.filter(delete=1)
```

It is always a good practice to write as little logic as possible inside the templates.